# TeXworks viewer shows only part of compiled document

Tags: texworks

I'm trying to find a LaTeX editor witch supports inverse search. I was trying TeXworks and in the begining it was working. The only problem was that I didn't know how to set `.dvi` as an output format and `.pdf` displays a bit strange on my computer. I was trying to enter the configuration of the editor and probably I've done something wrong, because the editor's viewer stopped to show what I've added to the input. The file compiles without any problems, log file says about 7 pages of output, but on the screan there is only 3,5 pages of it. The same document with other viewers displays entirely.

I've decided to uninstall TeXworks and install it once again. The problem remains. After uninstallation, there were still some files, which I couldn't remove without using root privileges - I've decided to leave it. The files are:

```
maria@maria-laptop:~$ locate * texworks *
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/texworks.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/_usr_share_pixmaps_texworks.xpm
/usr/share/texmf/context/data/texworks
/usr/share/texmf/context/data/texworks/TUG
/usr/share/texmf/context/data/texworks/completion
/usr/share/texmf/context/data/texworks/configuration
/usr/share/texmf/context/data/texworks/texworks-context.rme
/usr/share/texmf/context/data/texworks/texworks-setup.ini
/usr/share/texmf/context/data/texworks/TUG/TeXworks.ini
/usr/share/texmf/context/data/texworks/completion/tw-context.txt
/usr/share/texmf/context/data/texworks/configuration/auto-indent-patterns.txt
/usr/share/texmf/context/data/texworks/configuration/delimiter-pairs.txt
/usr/share/texmf/context/data/texworks/configuration/smart-quotes-modes.txt
/usr/share/texmf/context/data/texworks/configuration/syntax-patterns.txt
/usr/share/texmf/context/data/texworks/configuration/tag-patterns.txt
/usr/share/texmf/context/data/texworks/configuration/texworks-config.txt
/usr/share/texmf/scripts/context/lua/mtx-texworks.lua
```

Is it possible that the problem lies in those files? If not - in what else?

Thanks for any suggestions.

p.s.

This is the preamble with a little part of document:

```
%& --translate-file=utf-8
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[active]{srcltx}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\begin{document} 

\thispagestyle{empty}
\section*{Wstęp}
Istotą monoteizmu jest przekonanie, że Bóg jest jeden i nie ma współtowarzyszy;
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without an example document it's hard to say _why_ you only see part of the output. The files you list inside `/usr/share/texmf/context/data/` seem to be placed incorrect, but can be safely removed.

Comment: Why should that directory be incorrect? It is the default for texworks.

Comment: Also, which operating system are we talking about: from the context I assume Linux, but I might be wrong. If it _is_ Linux, what was the source and version of TeXworks?

Comment: @Herbert: Normally the config. files live inside `~`

Comment: @Joseph yes, it's linux, Ubuntu 10.4. Sorry for omission. Version of TeXworks: 0.2.3 (r.466). I've installed by apt-get. And as for default directory: in TeXworks is /usr/bin/ (that's what is stated in preferences, I haven't change it)

Comment: @Joseph: the local config files are in `~/Texworks/` but not the system wide ones ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that TeXworks can show a dvi. So if you change your document and compile only to dvi TeXworks will still show the pdf of the previous version. You will have to add dvips + ps2pdf or dvipdfmx to the call to latex.

Comment: Thanks. In effect, compilation with PdfLaTeX results with full output. Just one thing - I don't understand very well the last sentence. What should I do? I really prefere working on dvi. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I thought you can add more commands to the latex button but this doesn't seem to be the case. You will need a batch file. Apart from this: TeXworks is pdf orientated. It is not the best choice if you prefer dvi.

Comment: I prefere .dvi because .pdf displays a bit strange - all dashes are in bold. As I'm using a lot of it - in transcription, some characters has a dash above or below the letter - it makes a tekst looking strange. If I can get rid of it I can use pdf without problems. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get with texworks and TeXLive 2010 with pdflatex:

[image: pdflatex]

and the same with running latex for a dvi output

[image]

I have texworks 0.2.3 and used the files:

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  srcltx.sty    2006/11/12 v1.6 Source specials for inverse search in DVI files

  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
   babel.sty    2008/07/06 v3.8l The Babel package
  polish.ldf    2005/03/31 v1.2l Polish support from the babel system
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
   utf8x.def    2004/10/17 UCS: Input encoding UTF-8
     ucs.sty    2004/10/17 UCS: Unicode input support
uni-global.def    2004/10/17 UCS: Unicode global data
 ucsencs.def    2003/11/29 Fixes to fontencodings LGR, T3
   uni-1.def    2004/10/17 UCS: Unicode data U+0100..U+01FF
   uni-0.def
```

Comment: But the problem is not in displaying first sentence. First of all, I think the file is all right as it compiles even in TeXworks without errors or warnings. If I use other editor everything is ok (but I need inverse search). Second: Pdf displays only three pages of document. Third, even if I compile with LaTex and not PdfLaTeX, the output is pdf.

Comment: I never used the dvi output. Do you have to display the dvi or do you create a pdf from the dvi and view this one?

Comment: Usually I was using mostly dvi (generated by LaTeX) and pdf only if I wanted to send it (generated by pdfLaTeX). DVI displays better on the screen (at least in my computer). On windows I was using TeXnic Center and it's icons for building etc, after changing to ubuntu I was using terminal to compile (latex or pdflatex and file.tex), working in gedit.

Comment: I have a script called LaTeX (upper L) which I run from texworks. It conmpiles with latex and the opens xdvi in the background with the document.

Comment: How should I use it? If I open a document in TeXworks, it opens two windows, one of editor (where LaTeX is set as compiler), other with viewer which seems to be a part of TeXworks, not xdvi. In any case, it's a pdf file.

Comment: @maria: you have to edit the prefences for latex. Go to edit=>preferences and then the right card, don't know how it is named in english. Then choose latex and enable the checkmark for viewing the pdf output.

Comment: @Herbert: latex was already choosen, checkmark `View pdf after running` is on or off, the same happens - in the second window I have pdf output... And only 3,5 pages of 7...

Comment: @maria: can you please check your _tex_ file that you do not have a special first line which defines the used compiler: like `%& pdflatex ...`

Comment: @Herbert: no, I havent. All preamble is joint to my question. If I enter in the termial `latex file.tex` and after `xdvi file.dvi`, it opens as it should, an entirely. It should be a problem with my TeXworks settings.

Comment: @maria: and you are also sure, that you have latex twice in your config file? As name for the script and name for the program. btw: the local config file is in `~/.Texworks/configurations/tools.ini`

Comment: @Herbert: this is part of this file concerning LaTeX: [001]
name=LaTeX
program=latex
arguments=$synctexoption, $fullname
showPdf=false

Comment: @maria: that is correct and I am lost ... sorry

Comment: @Herbert: as well as me... I would just like to use inverse search under linux, as I used to under windows...

Comment: @maria: a last idea, please delete the pdf and all other files except the tex, then start texworks. Does it show a pdf after compiling with latex?

Comment: @Herbert: I've done what you told me. LaTeX compiles the document (dvi appears in the folder), but TeXworks viewer doesn't open it, even if I switch on the option `view pfd after running`. It seems that you can compile dvi file, but not view it with TeXworks.

Comment: @maria: sure, that is what I expected. You have to create a small script called `myLaTeX` which is called from texworks and runs `latex` and then `xdvi`

Comment: @Herbert: Unfortunatly I have no idea how to create such a script... I think I will rather try to find out why pdf files display strange, especially as it concerns only pdf files generated with LaTeX.